# How to redefine massaction actions in grid ui-component sales_order_grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, order-grid

In my custom extension i have tried modify section `massaction name="listing_massaction"`. Just copy content from ui_component/sales_order_grid only keep actions neccessary but after clear cache, magento still combine all action from module magento_sales

Thinks i have done

Overwrite layout `sales_order_index` in my directory adminhtml/layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="sales_order_grid"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

ui_component/sales_order_grid

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="custom_print_orders" class="Company\Extension\Ui\Component\Action">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">custom_print_orders</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom PDF - Print Orders</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="custom_print_invoices" class="Company\Extension\Ui\Component\Action">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">custom_print_invoices</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom PDF - Print Invoices</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="custom_print_shipments" class="Company\Extension\Ui\Component\Action">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">custom_print_shipments</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Easy PDF - Print Shipments</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="custom_print_creditmemos" class="Company\Extension\Ui\Component\Action">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">custom_print_creditmemos</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom PDF - Print Creditmemos</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
```

Is there a way to remove original or disable action in massaction grid ui ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create component for that. So add class attribute like bellow code:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" class="Vendor\Module\Component\MassAction">
    ......
</massaction>
```

**Vendor/Module/Component/MassAction.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Component;


class MassAction extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
{
    protected $removeType = ['cancel', 'hold_order'];
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        $config = $this->getConfiguration();

        foreach ($this->getChildComponents() as $actionComponent) {
            $config['actions'][] = $actionComponent->getConfiguration();
        };

        $origConfig = $this->getConfiguration();
        if ($origConfig !== $config) {
            $config = array_replace_recursive($config, $origConfig);
        }

        $newConfigActions = [];
        foreach ($config['actions'] as $configItem) {
            if(in_array($configItem['type'], $this->removeType)) {
                continue;
            }

            $newConfigActions[] = $configItem;
        }

        $config['actions'] = $newConfigActions;

        $this->setData('config', $config);
        $this->components = [];

        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

Comment: Work like a charm!

Comment: It's not working for me, my module in placed in app/code , magento version 2.3